# Read Excel from DB2

Tags: excel, db2, oledb, external-tables, table-functions

I have to import some Excel data on a regular basis. Checking the [DB2 documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0002170.html) one can directly access OLE DB datasources via an external function.

However I'm unable to set it up properly. I got the [Microsoft Access Database Enginge 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) plus the fix pack and installed it on the database server.

I placed the excel file in a local directory from the database server. (`C:\Temp\test.xls`)

The excel has a workbook called `TEST1` and two rows `ABC` and `DEF` following some numeric data:

```
ABC | DEF
---------
1   | 5
2   | 6
3   | 7
4   | 8
```

For creating the table function I used the following statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MYSCHEMA.test_excel ()
  RETURNS TABLE(ABC INTEGER,
            DEF INTEGER)
LANGUAGE OLEDB
EXTERNAL NAME '!TEST1!Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
      Data Source=C:\Temp\test.xls;
  Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"';
```

It seems to create that function. However when querying the data with:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(MYSCHEMA.test_excel()) AS FUNCTABLE;
```

I'm getting the following error:

> User defined function "MYSCHEMA.TEST_EXCEL" received an OLE DB error from specified OLE DB provider.  HRESULT="0x80040e37". Diagnostic text: "The Microsoft Access database engine".. SQLCODE=-1183, SQLSTATE=38506, DRIVER=3.53.71

According to the [documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.licensing.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0053238.html) the error means: `0x80040E37 The specified table does not exist.`

The `!TEST!` should reference the workbook, however I'm unsure if it is correct syntax. How can one access a Excel worksheet from DB2? Is there a way to get a more detailed error message? Does anyone the correct naming scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The naming seems to be incorrect. Looking at other oledb samples I figured a '$' was missing.

`!TEST$!` works as an external name when referencing a worksheet called `TEST` and I can access the data.